# The pythonic way to remove a list item thats is 'sub-list' of another

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have this method that gets all valid moves from a checkers board.

```
def get_all_moves(self) -> list:
    moves = []
    pieces = self.__get_all_turn_pieces()

    for p in pieces:
        self.__jump_moves(p.coord, moves)
        self.__b.wipe()
        self.__simple_moves(p, moves)

    moves.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    for i in range(len(moves)):
        for j in range(len(moves)):
            if moves[i][:len(moves[j])] == moves[j] and len(moves[i]) > len(moves[j]):
                moves.remove(moves[j])
    return moves
```

The problem is: by the rules of checkers the player has to execute the most number of captures in his move. Therefore I need to remove the invalid moves.

Lets analysis this output:

```
[[3, 0, 5, 2, 3, 4], [5, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4], [1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 4, 2, 3], [2, 5, 3, 6], [2, 5, 3, 4], [2, 7, 3, 6], [3, 0, 5, 2], [5, 0, 3, 2]]
```

The first and second items of output list contain, respectively, the last two ones. So I need to remove them because they are 'sub-list' of the first ones.

The problem is my nested loop cannot solve this problem. The program spill this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "damas.py", line 435, in <module>
    print(m.get_all_moves())
  File "damas.py", line 418, in get_all_moves
    if moves[i][:len(moves[j])] == moves[j] and len(moves[i]) > len(moves[j]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After awhile, I'm wondering what is the most *pythonic* way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have worked out, the problem is that you're only checking the length of `moves` for `i` once at the beginning. When you remove items from it, you shorten it, which results in the loop variable `i` eventually advancing beyond the size of the list.

There are a variety of ways to remedy this. My usual approach for this sort of situation, where you have to evaluate every element in a list for removal, is to start at the *end* of the list and work back toward the start.

```
for i in reversed(range(len(moves))):
    for j in range(len(moves)):
        if i != j and moves[i] == moves[j][:len(moves[i])]:
            del moves[i]
            break
```

Note that I am evaluating `moves[i]` for removal, and not `moves[j]`. If I find that I want to remove it, I do so and then immediately break out of the inner `for` loop. This will only affect the structure of the list *at and after* position `i` (the items we've already considered and have decided to keep), not before (the items we have yet to consider). Therefore, we won't run into any pesky IndexErrors.

Comment: Besides solving the problem. Correct the error of my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dagdeloo I just made one small change. Instead of using `list.remove()` to drop items, I changed it to use `del`. This will avoid a potential issue if you were to have duplicate items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the most pythonic way of doing things, but this is a variant of something I've used for checking substrings which is pretty concise:

```
def check_for_sublist(sub_list,longer_list): 
    return any(sub_list == longer_list[offset:offset+len(sub_list)] for offset in range(len(longer_list)))
```

Or a lambda version, which I've been advised not to use in the comments. Left it here as a learning tool as I learnt something from the comment!

```
x_sublist_y = lambda x, y: any(x == y[offset:offset+len(x)] for offset in range(len(y)))
```

And then I think this will do the trick. It creates a list of entries for which `arraycheck` doesn't return True (making sure to exclude checking terms against themselves).

```
moves = [[3, 0, 5, 2, 3, 4], [5, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4], [1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 4, 2, 3], [2, 5, 3, 6], [2, 5, 3, 4], [2, 7, 3, 6], [3, 0, 5, 2], [5, 0, 3, 2]]

filtered_moves = [move1 for move1 in moves if all([not check_for_sublist(move1, move2) for move2 in moves if move1 != move2])]
```

Comment: Don't assign the results of a lambda to a name, that removes the only advantage, that they are *anonymous*. Otherwise, just use a normal function definition. This is a PEP8 guideline as well...

Comment: Fair enough. I just changed it here to make it clearer what was going on, but have edited it back.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I realised I misunderstood your comment. Have made another change. Thanks for pointing it out, it's not something I've really thought about before.

Comment: Very interesting. It works perfectly, of course I'll keep this function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a list comprehension, which is often a useful approach when you want to make things as Pythonic as possible

```
def is_sublist( seq, lists ):
    for candidate in lists:
        if len( candidate ) > len( seq ) and candidate[ :len( seq ) ] == seq:
            return True
    return False

moves = [[3, 0, 5, 2, 3, 4], [5, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4], [1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 4, 2, 3], [2, 5, 3, 6], [2, 5, 3, 4], [2, 7, 3, 6], [3, 0, 5, 2], [5, 0, 3, 2]]

# here comes the list comprehension:
pruned = [ eachMove for eachMove in moves if not is_sublist( eachMove, moves ) ]
```

To modify the sequence `moves` in-place, you would assign to `moves[:]` instead of to a new variable `pruned`.

However, the solution above is not the most efficient, which may be a concern if the number of potential moves is large.  A less-elegant-looking approach like the following may be advisable because, as candidate moves get rejected, we reduce the number of potential superlists against which each future potential sublist must be checked:

```
accepted = []
while moves:
    eachMove = moves.pop( 0 )
    if not is_sublist( eachMove, moves ) and not is_sublist( eachMove, accepted ):
        accepted.append( eachMove )

moves[:] = accepted
```

If the ordering of the list of moves is not important, performing `moves.sort()` at the top of this routine will make it more efficient (in fact, then we could optimize the code even further, because each move only ever has to be compared against the *next* move in the list).